# Android Studio, rather than opening file, dumps memory to the text editor

Tags: android, android-studio

[Example of what opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykjnr.png)

I think it is dumping memory, because the strings and file names are not related to the project. I have tried invalidating caches, restarts, and computer restarts. Nothing fixes it. Everything compiles fine, and this only affects ~50% of the files.

Edit: And following the directions to "change encoding" doesn't fix it either

Comment: I think your file corrupted

Comment: I can open the files in other text editors perfectly fine, and it compiles fine, so it's definitely just IntelliJ